# Flexbox is not fitting on mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is my first week working with flexbox, and I like it a lot until now. I am doing everything I can to get away of floating elements. Therefore my main purpose is not a solution there is floating elements in. I run into 2 problems, that I am not quite sure of the correct saolution.

**Problem 1:**
When I hit around 1200px I can see the 2 columns is starting moving together. How can that be?

**Problem 2:**
Why is my columns not fitting on viewport under 768px? I can see on the mobile the `900x200` is going over the edge of the max width on telephone.

[Example page of my code here](http://dev.mimsi.dk/02_local-index.html).

```css
.column-layout {
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
}

.column-layout-one {
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
}

.header-item-one {
  order: 1;
}

.header-item-two {
  order: 2;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .column-layout-one {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="column-layout-one">
  <div class="header-item-one">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/280x200">
  </div>
  <div class="header-item-two">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/900x200">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you asking here, exactly? You have placeholder images that take up 900 pixels in width, though you try to fit under 768 px. Are you looking to crop the images?

Comment: The correct solution would be that they stack on top of each other maybe?

Comment: Can you add image of expected results ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.column-layout {
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
}
img {max-width: 100%;}
.column-layout-one {
  max-width: 1200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
}

.header-item-one {
  order: 1;
}

.header-item-two {
  order: 2;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .column-layout-one {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="column-layout-one">
  <div class="header-item-one">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/280x200">
  </div>
  <div class="header-item-two">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/900x200">
  </div>
</div>
```

1. When I hit around 1200px I can see the 2 columns is starting moving together. How can that be?

Your `.column-layout-one` has max width 1200 set, inner elements has 280+900 = 1180 px, and you have used `space-between` on its parent. so, when the parent has space more than its defined width, inner items will be seprated by diffrence of 1200-1180 = 20px; as soon as its parent will shrink this space will reduce, because its the space left by these 2 divs,

`Space-between = outerWidth - (Total of inner width)`

2. if you want your images to fit in screen on mobile, then provide it 
   `max-width: 100%`, if you will not do so, itwill take its orignal width and distort your design.

Comment: if you always want to maintain the gap of 20px between both the div's till they will be side by side, let me know, I will change the code accordingly, bu I hipe now you know the reason why the gap is reducing while hitting 1200px point

Comment: I didn't get you, what is the output you want? the way you used flex is good, only thing is , your order property will not work on mobile as you have given display flex on min-width 768

Comment: you can not have the same behave with images, it is possible but then you need to compromise with image appearance , let me give you an example.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2jgd6snb/1/ , check this, but as you can see the image view is not as same as before

Comment: Thank you @Atul. I really think this coding is horrible sometimes. I was so happy with the flexbox, since I have been working with Bootstrap for years, and is using hours and hours for fixing the float problem. I thought that Flexbox could solve this, but that is only with text I guess then. So basically there is no reason of learning the flexbox then.

Comment: So the problem will be exact the same as Bootstrap. Then I want to add some text and CTA over the image, and the text will go out of the flexbox. What is there else af solutions? The CSS grid is way to much work. I am working with a grid I have to change almost everyday, so I do not have time to switch around on the CSS grid. Is it to set background images instead?

Comment: I just do not understand how everybody else can solve this problem except me. What are https://www.asos.com/women/ fx doing?

Comment: You shown me the asos.com example above... So as you can see the difference in image on desktop and on mobile , on Desktop there are 2 girls in view , while on mobile only one... That is what my fiddle solution. Is doing.. u can have any text or cta in that div and make it center with flexbox.

Comment: Is there a way to mix Bootstrap and flexbox? So use the Boostrap grid, but control height with flexbox regarding keeping the height of the columns. All my problems the past 4 years is keeping the height of columns, and I have to hack around to make it fit. I am so dead right now to keep working my height problems on images in general. Do you have time to make the example with some text on top of the car image? https://jsfiddle.net/26v9q8jk/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215023/discussion-between-atul-rajput-and-mk-dk).

Answer (score 0):

Set your `.header-item-one` and `-two` to `flex: 1;` to fill up the whole space in your flex box. Then, set `max-width` values for the expected results.

```css
.header-item-one {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
}

.header-item-two {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 900px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
}
```

About the other problem -- the divs go over the viewport boundaries, because you have placeholder images. Images are fixed-width inline block elements, meaning they *won't* fit the user's viewport, unless you crop them out with `overflow-x: hidden;` in the parent div or do something like `div img { max-width: 100%; }`.

Remove the images and try out that css. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/59meh6vs/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just changed the placeholder images to normal images: http://dev.mimsi.dk/02_local-index.html. Regarding the width, is it not better to set a "flex-basis"?

Comment: I just looked at the page on my mobile, and can see the car image is still going way over the viewport.